# Check shell variable failing when it returns null list

Tags: bash, azure, shell, unix

**Objective:** Trying to check if resource exist on azure with bash script

**Code that I use :**

```
status=$(az group list --query "[?name.contains(@,'test')]")
if [[ "$status" == null ]];
then
   echo "not exist"
else
   echo "exist"
fi
```

I have this resource in azure i.e it should return as "exist" however its says not exist
If I change to a non existant resource group name then time also its gives not exist.

do you see any syntax issue here ?

Instead of script if I execute at commmand line to check , below are results

```
user@ablab:~$ status=$(az group list --query "[?name.contains(@,'abcd')]")
user@ablab:~$ echo $status
[]
user@ablab:~$ status=$(az group list --query "[?name.contains(@,'test')]")
user@ablab:~$ echo $status
[ { "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxx--xxxxx3/resourceGroups/test1", "location": "westeurope", "managedBy": null, "name": "test1", "properties": { "provisioningState": "Succeeded" }, "tags": null, "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups" } ]
```

Now I wanna use if condition, so that if its exist it should process set of flow else set of code..

Please let me know what wrong with my if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is fine. However, I don't see from your example, that `az` would write the string `null` to stdout. In the first case, it prints, according to what you posted, the string `[]`. To catch this case, you would have to test

```
if [[ $status == '[]' ]]
then
  ...
```

The quotes around the string tell bash to not interpret it as a glob pattern.

Comment: `status=$(az group list --query "[?name.contains(@,'test')]")
if [[ "$status" == '[]' ]]
then
   echo "not exist"
else
   echo "exist"
fi`  this still gives exist whether I give existing resource or non existing resource name

Comment: `./test.sh: 2: [[: not found
exist` so when I run above i get this error

Comment: In this case, it means that you don't run bash. You can verify this to do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` near the start of the script. If you don't get a reasonable version number, you don't run bash.

Comment: Strangely this is not working on vm which i was testing, but when i run it on CI pipeline on cloud, ur suggestion worked  == '[ ]' worked

Comment: Well, what do you get for BASH_VERSION on vm then?